# Show that solution decays to 0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x=x(t)$ and for a constant $a\in (0,1)$ consider the initial value problem
$$
x'(t) = x (1-x)(x-a),\quad 0\leq x(0)<a.
$$

I want to show that this implies that $x(t)\downarrow 0$ as $t\to\infty$.

---

Do I have to solve by separating variables, i.e.
$$
\int\frac{1}{x(1-x)(x-a)}\, dx= t +c?
$$

Comment: No, you don't have to solve explicitly. What can you say about $x'(t)$ if $0 < x(t) < a$?

Comment: Ah, I see. If we start in $0\leq x(0)<a$, then there are to cases. (1) $x(0)=0$. Then we are in an equilibrium and stay there forever, i.e. $x(t)=0$ for all $t\geq 0$. (2) If $0<x(0)<a$, then $x'(t)<0$, i.e. $x(t)$ decreases till we reach $x(t)=0$. But to know that $x(t)\to 0$ we need to know that $x(t)\geq 0$ additionally, right?